# Реализация интерфейса с методами возвращающие обьект интерфейса

Tags: c#

Что то запутался на простом

```
 public interface IListItem //элемент списка
{
    IListItem Prev(); //предыдущий элемент
    IListItem Next(); //следующий элемент
    object Value { get; } //значение, хранимое в элементе
}

 public class ListItem : IListItem
{
    public IListItem prev { get; set; }
    public IListItem next { get; set; }
    object Value { get; }

    public ListItem(object obj, IListItem prev = null)
    {
         if(obj!=null) Value = obj;

        //логика инициализации
    }

}
```

И как реализовать эти методы IListItem Prev() IListItem Next() из интерфейса?
Пишу

```
   public IListItem Prev()
    {
        return prev;

    }

    public IListItem Next()
    {
        return next;

    }
```

ругается [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну так мы откуда знаем какая вам логика нужна

Comment: @Андрей Посмотрите на картинку, я просто хочу вернуть значения, чтоб интерфейс был реализован, а там ошибка

Comment: Вы придумали себе какие-то интерфейсы, которые не можете реализовать? Может они вам и не нужны вообще?

Comment: Это задание тест, не я их придумал, можете просто исправить ошибку, это двухсвязанный самоопределнный список надо сделать, здесь застопорился, сложное понятное а на простом застрял

Comment: Ну сообщение об ошибке прямо вам говорит, что интерфейс содержит некий член Value, который отсутствует в реализации. Вернее что он не публичный

Answer (score 1):

Невозможно присваивать значение свойству, у которого нет приставки set;
Измените на

```
public object Value { get; set; }
```

Comment: Ну вообще-то в конструкторе можно (с некоторых пор). Да и у автора не на это ругается

Comment: public я также добавил (ответ был изменён)